# UIWebView toggling scalespagetofit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a situation where I want to load some html

```
<html><body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><img src="/++video?cameraNum=15&width=640&height=480&noScaleUp=1&auth=cmhiOkJpZ01hYw==&7427" width=341 height=256></body></html>
```

When I set the scalesPageToFit = YES in (checked in IB) I can pinch to zoom the webview but the initial load of the image is too small for the webview:

[image]

If I set scalesPageToFit = NO in (unchecked in IB) then the video feed scales properly upon loading, but now the user can not pinch to zoom the picture.
[image]

Of course, what I need is for the webpage to load up properly sized AND then allow the user to pinch to zoom, double tap to reset gestures.

Anyone know of a way to do this in either code or javascript etc... ?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use meta tag in your  i have one sample that is used in ma project.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" id="iphone-viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width>
```

Is this useful?

Comment: Yes!  That took care of it for my situation.  By the way there is a complete reference in the Apple Docs here: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html) and here [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193)